# Windows Firewall. Can't get to allow a specific program over local network

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, router, firewall

i'm desperately trying to make Windows Firewall allow the UDP connection of a client/server software between 2 locally connected computer (using a router)

When i try with the windows firewall off on both server and client side, everything works perfectly, indicating me that Windows Firewall is the culprit

i would like to get the server/client to be able to communicate with each other with the firewall active on both client and server side but everything i've tried yet didn't work.

What i've tried so far:

-added the executable in "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall" on both sever and client side

-i tried to create a inbound rule allowing connections from 
all UDP port using a specific executable on both server/client side

-tried to deactivate the Web agent from Avast Antivirus (server side), client side should not have anything 2rd party blocking the connection as it is a fresh install.

-tried to allow all inbound connections on the Private Profile in the "Windows Firewall with advanced Security on Local Computer Properties" window, again on both client and server (at this point i was trial testing almost everything)

anyone have ideas that could fix the problem?

Comment: Is there another rule in Windows firewall that also blocks the port you are trying to allow?